# How to duplicate "title" <a> as a "alt" of "img". using regex, manually?

Tags: regex, xhtml, dreamweaver

How to add title of link as a alt of img. using regex and in dreamweaver. I have to do in a large document. and in multiple files

Before

```
<a title="Whatever is written here" href="#" target="_blank">
<img width="14" height="14" src="#" /></a>
```

after

```
<a title="Whatever is written here" href="#" target="_blank">
<img width="14" height="14" src="#" alt="Whatever is written here" /></a>
```

Comment: probably not a good idea to use regex, unless you want to manually check it all.

Comment: then how  to add quickly. i have to add alt in images with same text of title. title is already available in <a>

Comment: @Paul he is working in a HTML editor, he's not looking to change it programmatically. Using regexes is valid (actually, the only way) in this case.

Comment: @Pekka - you are absolutely right

Comment: @Pekka, it might be the only way to do it in dreamweaver, but that doesn't make it right! I could write a regex, but i'd have to sure that the structure of every link0 was the same, or i'd have to take every possible structure into account. If you can say with 100% confidence that all the links have identical structure, with the same order of attributes and no potential for meta characters anywhere, then go for it, otherwise accept that the results will not be perfect unless you use a better tool.

Comment: @Paul I totally agree with you, but from what I'm seeing, the OP has a defined structure in this case (one or several HTML pages opened in his editor) and needs to perform a defined operation on them. I really think a regex is okay here, and I think it's safe to assume the structure is the same. Even though technically, this being a Dreamweaver question makes it "not programming related" :)

Comment: Qpaul - `img` will be always inside link but images size, image name, text inside `title` cab be changed

Comment: @jitendra, can you perhaps tell us which regexes you've already tried, and perhaps explain to us why they didn't work? Did you search for any regular expression or Dreamweaver help before you asked this question, and if so, what did you find? If you tell us that, we might be able to actually help you, rather than give you a copy/paste answer and have you ask another, similar question tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for

```
(<a[^>]+?title=")([^"]*)("[^<]+<img)
```

and replacing with

```
$1$2$3 alt="$2"
```

This assumes that there is no other tag between the `<a>` tag and the `<img>` tag, and that there are no (escaped) quotes inside the `title` attribute.

EDIT: Changed `\1` backreference syntax to `$1`.

Comment: Please try an alternate syntax: Use `$1$2$3 alt="$2"` as replace string.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to write a script in some scriptiong language (ruby, python etc.) that:

1. Goes through all the files
2. Finds in file <img> tag.
3. Checks whether there is an <a> around it (as parent)
4. Puts value of the img.alt to a.title.

There are already some libraties to parse html/xml ([ruby.hpricot](http://hpricot.com/) for example)

Comment: but i don't know ruby python etc.